# Convert hexstring to bigint with out node.js dependency

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to convert a hex string to a BigInt.

I cannot use the default BigInt from node.js where it works just fine since i am using React-native.

I tried using [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) but i get the error:

```
 Invalid integer
```

Basic example here:
https://playcode.io/943259

Displayed is how the native BigInt converts a hex string successfully to a BigInt.
Then you can comment out the second part where i import BigInt from big-integer and it will throw the error.

```
let hexString ='0x9c46e9ec68e9bd4fe1faaba294cba38a71aa177534cdd1b6c7dc0dbd0abd7a7';
console.log('HexString to BigInt', BigInt(hexString));
//uncomment to get the error
//import BigInt from 'big-integer'
//console.log('HexString to BigInt', BigInt(hexString));
```

Comment: I do not see an issue in you playground.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] _in the question itself_

Comment: @Palladium02 If you uncomment the commented out code it will throw an error in the console.

Comment: @Andreas i provided a playground is that not sufficient?

Comment: From my first link: _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself.** Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) cannot detect the radix from the string, but you can specify it

```js
import BigInt from 'big-integer'
let hexString ='0x9c46e9ec68e9bd4fe1faaba294cba38a71aa177534cdd1b6c7dc0dbd0abd7a7';
console.log('HexString to BigInt', BigInt(hexString.substring(2), 16));
```